# Memcache on windows, error php5.dll not found

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I use PHP 5.3.0 and after hours of searching found a `php_memcache.dll` that is compiled for that version, now as I start php it gives me an error

> The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

As I see it there is `php5ts.dll` in php folder, and I can't find `php5.dll`.

And as a result memcache does not start.
How can I fix this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592739/program-cant-start-because-php5-dll-is-missing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old question, but are you sure the php_memcache.dll you downloaded is a thread-safe/unsafe compatible with your PHP install?

Look in your PHP directory: if there's a "php5ts.dll" you have a thread-safe PHP, so you need a thread-safe "php_memcache.dll" too, and vice-versa.

I had the same problem, with a diferent php_*.dll, and the error message about php5.dll confused the heck out of me for several hours too, but it was just a matter of downloading the right php_*.dll.

Comment: @kibemau, Would doing the alternative work? I.e. [downloading `php5.dll`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046142/632951), putting it in our directory, and doing it the nts way.

Comment: you just saved my ass sir. I had to go get an Thread safe memcache.dll from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows
Thanks

Comment: In my case, it happened when I update my old Xampp install, compiled with VC11 (PHP 5.6) to a new one, compiled with VC15 (PHP 7.2). The memcache PHP extension (php_memcache-3.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip) which used to work with my old Xampp, stoped working with the new one, giving me this message. I guess it will be solved, when I update this extension to a new one, compatible with PHP 7.2 and compiled with VC15

Answer (score -1):

1. download `php5.dll`
2. copy and paste to ""

Answer (score -4):

Most likely your `memcache_php.dll` files needs `php5.dll` file to be able to work correctly.

I suppose it should be distributed as part of that memcache for PHP. Or you can google about `php5.dll` to know more about it.

Comment: Your answer is all one can find about this error (with dozens of sites mirroring this exact question)...