# program cant start because php5.dll is missing

Tags: php, debugging

1. I installed XAMPP , phpinfo: PHP Version 5.3.5
2. Downloaded PHPPDT, installed
3. downloaded webserver debug extension, copied dummy.php
4. added zend_extension="c:\edward\xampp\php\ext\5_3_x_nts_comp\ZendDebugger.dll"

stop, restart apache, get:

"the program cant start because php5.dll is missing from your computer"

(while php5nts.dll is included)

is installing zend studio ce the alternative or can i make it work with XAMPP? (using Zend Studio CE works)

Comment: already exist [duplicate][1] question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306132/memcache-on-windows-error-php5-dll-not-found

Comment: yes the other answer is "google for the answer" did not bring me anything new

Comment: If you got here from google, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975875/868321

Answer (score 38, accepted):

if your php version is Non-Thread-Safe (nts) 
you must use php extension with format example: extension=php_cl_dbg_5_2_**nts**.dll
else if your php version is Thread-Safe (ts)
you must use php extension with format example: extension=php_cl_dbg_5_2_**ts**.dll
(notice bolded words)

So if get error like above.  Firstly, check your PHP version is nts  or ts, if is **nts**.
Then check in php.ini whether has any line like    zend_extension_**ts**="C:\xammp\php\ext\php_dbg.dll-5.2.x" choose right version of php_dbg.dll-5.2.x from it homepage (google for it). 
Change from zend_extension_**ts** to zend_extension_**nts**.

Hope this help.

Comment: My php version in thread safe, but having same problem. What to do for thread safe php?

Comment: Note that ending the filename with `nts.dll` and `ts.dll` is just a convention. It's totally possible for a nts dll to be named as `ts.dll` and vice-versa.

Comment: The proper method is to check you currently installed PHP is it nts version or ts version. TS version would have php5ts.dll inside of your php folder; while regular NTS version would have php.dll inside of your php folder. Don't simply copy over php5.dll, instead re-configure your php.ini not to use or to use NTS/TS version of extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Download php5.dll (http://windows.php.net/download/) and copy it to apache/bin folder. That solved it for me (Win 7 64 bit apache 32 bit)

**EDIT:**
Start with the non-thread safe version.

Answer (score 3):

For Wamp x86+Phalcon users *(with same error)*:

Take care of download the right version of Phalcon:

Phalcon 1.3.2 - Windows **x86** for PHP 5.5.0 (**VC11**)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem I switched from wamp to xampp and yes PHP was working because my path was still pointing to my old installation. I had forgotten to change it to point to my new php installation which version of php didn't match the rest at all.

Answer (score 2):

In case this might help someone, after installing the thread safe version of PHP 5.5.1, everything was working under apache for my dev sites, but I ran into the same "php5.dll is missing" problem installing Composer using the Composer-Setup.exe - or, as I soon discovered, just running something as simple as php -v from the command line. I made a copy of php5ts.dll and named it php5.dll and everything worked. I assume the Composer installer was specifically looking for "php5.dll" and I knew that the thread safe code would be run by the renamed .dll. I also assume something is wrong with my setup to screw up the command line functionality, but with everything working, I have more important issues to deal with than to try and find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just now faced this issue while trying to restart XAMPP Apache.

What you can do to solve this is:

1. download PHP5.dll from http://originaldll.com/file/php5.dll/30704.html
2. Copy the downloaded php5.dll to C:\xampp\php
3. Start APACHE and MySql from XAMPP control panel

Hope my solution solves your problem.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change environment variable `PATH` and `PHPRC`. Also open new `cmd`.

I already had PHP installed and added EasyPHP when the problem came up. After I changed both variables to `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\php\php_runningversion` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you open phpinfo() 
see if the thread safety is enable or not enable 
also see the version of php 
and see MSVC-- what is the number in place of --
and see the architecture 
these all things help u to get the suitable php driver

here a url help u to get a php driver
  https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to solve this is:

1. Download **PHP5.dll** or **PHP7.dll** from: http://windows.php.net/download/.
2. Copy the downloaded **php5.dll** or **php7.dll** to `C:\xampp\php`.
3. Start Apache and MySQL from XAMPP Control Panel.