# phpunit - Windows php.exe error

Tags: php, phpunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [program cant start because php5.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592739/program-cant-start-because-php5-dll-is-missing)

I got this error when i try to launch my tests in command line:

> The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try re installing the program to fix the problem.

How can i fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592739/program-cant-start-because-php5-dll-is-missing

Comment: k thanks arxanas, i'll give a try

Comment: yes i don't understand the answer on that question at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding your php directory and your php extensions directory to your PATH environment variables.

Comment: @Aknosis, Isn't setting [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) a better solution?

Comment: @Pacerier I have had this same problem with php.ini extension_dir set. I'm pretty sure this is very specific to running mod_php and Apache on windows. If you are using a diff webserver and/or php-fpm you may not need this fix.

Comment: @Aknosis, Are you sure you `extension_dir` is not working? It should work regardless of your setup, else its a bug with the SAPI (and that's unlikely) isn't it?