# The program can’t start because php5ts.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have a Win 2008 r2 server that has been running PHP 5.3 and convinced client to upgrade to 5.6.19 which is the latest available at the time of this post. This instance runs Apache 2.2.

Because I want to keep this instance lean but able to move back to 5.3 if I failed I downloaded the **non-thread-safe** version. I've updated the soon-to-be commissioned php.ini (formerly the example production file) to be aligned with the params in the 5.3 php.ini. Then I pointed the server's PATH from the 5.3 folder to the new one containing the 5.6.19 files. I have not attempted to run Apache yet opting instead to test that the new PHP works at least with CMD. That's when I got the above message.

It would seem the consensus of these posts:
http://www.touchoftechnology.com/the-program-cant-start-because-php5ts-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error/#ixzz42KMHyQFz
[program cant start because php5.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592739/program-cant-start-because-php5-dll-is-missing)

that I should rename the php5.dll file to 'ts' or 'nts' in its file name and/or add this designation in the php.ini. But I don't see where to put it in the .ini file. Renaming php5.dll (from the installation files) to php5nts.dll returns the message that php5.dll is missing. I've tried many different combinations of these filenames, and even adding a php5ts.dll from a thread-safe distribution. I can't get one without the other.

One of the posts suggests adding the 'nts' to some of the Zend extensions but I'm not running zend on this production box. Where in the php.ini do I need to set the file I got (php5.dll) to solve this? I hope once I get the CLI working that the Apache should not have this problem.

Other comments say to run [Microsoft's Platform installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=&appid=PHP%3BPHP%3BPHP) but that seems to introduce more things that are not needed on this production box and I do not want any extra baggage. I just want to point Windows and Apache to this newer PHP install.

Answer (score 0):

I had read that for early Windows OS I should use the non-thread safe version of PHP. That version is missing the php5apache2_x.dll which caused doubt about this package. An acquaintance said to use the thread safe version which had the php5apache2_4.dll. It seemed to work in the Windows CMD browser after I set my environment variable to that folder. But digging further, it appears that I should also upgrade my Apache to 2.4 as later PHP and later Apache are using different Visual Studio compilers.