# MongoDB DLL on Windows XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I am runnning MSVC11 x86 and have added the corresponding drivers to ext and added it in the php.ini file.

I have attached screenshots of the errors and have followed what they have asked but they're not making a lot of sense, if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely case is that the driver DLL you're using is not compatible with your PHP runtime. A similar question on the subject is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540754/162228).

Each Windows driver release includes various DLLs for each permutation of PHP. For instance, the 1.5.7 release includes the following just for PHP 5.5:

- VC9
- VC9, NTS (not thread-safe)
- VC9, x86_64
- VC9, NTS, x86_64
- VC11
- VC11, NTS (not thread-safe)
- VC11, x86_64
- VC11, NTS, x86_64

I assume you're correctly using a VC11 DLL, but based on the error message I assume you're using an NTS or x64_64 DDL when you should not be.

The [PECL downloads](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.7/windows) do not specify whether builds are for VC9 or VC11. I believe builds for PHP 5.5+ are VC11, and all prior versions are VC9. That said, the zip releases published in the [S3 bucket](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) (referenced in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows)) do include builds for both VC runtimes for all supported PHP versions.

---

On a related note of DLL dependencies, you may encounter an error similar to "`php_mongo.dll` is not a valid Win32 application." If so, that may be due to `libsasl.dll` missing from your path. This is mentioned in the [Windows documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) for the driver and you'll find additional discussion of the issue in [PHP-1159](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1159).